# Two Jobs, Same Worker using ActiveJob w/ Sidekiq

Tags: sidekiq, rails-activejob

Is there a recommended convention for or against using the same job class for different jobs? I'm trying to avoid having to create a separate job class for child jobs spawned from the parent.

I realize Sidekiq::Batch may handle tracking spawned jobs from a parent, but it doesn't resolve using the same class for different jobs.

For example:

```
# not ideal: requires separate child job class
class ParentJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(*args)
    MyModel.all.each { |f| ChildJob.perform_later(f) }
  end
end

# ideal - allows re-use of same class
class ParentJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(*args)
    # doesn't work, but shown here conceptually
    MyModel.all.each { |f| self.class.perform(:foo, f) }
  end

  def foo(f); end
end
```

I could look at the parent job's args and if it contains a special key, branch and run a different method, but I dislike the ambiguous contract of that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two classes.  That's the Sidekiq best practice, that's the convention.  SRP and all that.